# Integration by Parts. Get original expression

Tags: calculus, integration

One of the engineering proofs I am trying to understand has the following line. It says using integration by parts the below can be shown:

$$\int(\sigma_{ij},_j * u_i)dV = \int((\sigma_{ij} * u_i),_j)dV - \int(\sigma_{ij} * u_i,_j) dV$$

N.b. The above is in einstein notation in which the comma represents partial diff.

I pulled out my notes but could not perform integration by parts for whatever reason. I arrived at the original expression. Any help appreciated!

Comment: [Here a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), so that you can learn some basis in latex and edit your question ;-)

Comment: Great, thank you! Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the standard version of partial integration. Partial integration in one variable says the following:

$$\int_a^bf(x)g'(x)dx = \int_a^b[f(x)g(x)]'dx - \int_a^bf'(x)g(x)dx.$$

Applied to your question, with some nicer notation (sometimes these shorthands like Einstein notation can cloud our vision):

$$\int \partial_j\sigma_{ij}\cdot u_idV = \int \partial_j(\sigma_{ij}u_i)dV-\int\sigma_{ij}\cdot\partial_ju_idV.$$